# Date Picker Bootstrap errors when input date (FireFox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap-datepicker with the following code:

```
$('#approved-date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
});
```

On Firefox browse, when I was typing date like "12/10/2   ", it gives errors:

[image]

The date is chosen automatically when typing like this:

[image]

How can I turn off the automation of selected date when typing?

Comment: One option can be adding *readonly* attribute to your input.

Comment: I want to input date on textbox

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<input type="..." disabled="disabled" />
```

Just add `disabled="disabled"` to your input field
or `<input type="text" autocomplete="on | off">` if you wont remove autocomplete

Comment: I want to turn off the auto chosen date when typing

Comment: I have already tried your suggest, but it doesn't solve my problem